# Running multiple traceroutes at the same time

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I'm writing a program that runs trace routes (using tracert in Windows) on IP-addresses in a database, manipulates the response and stores it. I have worked this all out, but the program takes too long to run. The database contains ~5000 IP-addresses and every trace takes ~30 seconds. This is what the code looks like now:

```
output_files = getOutputFiles(output_dir)
ip_or_list = getIpsORs(server, user, passhash)

for obj in ip_or_list:
    ip = obj[0]
    order_nr = obj[1]
    trace = runTrace(ip)

    output_filename = order_nr + '___' + ip + '.txt'
    if output_filename in output_files:
        handleOutput(output_filename, trace)
    else:
        newOutputFile(output_filename, trace)
        handleOutput(output_filename, trace)
```

This executes the code linearly, going through every IP in ip_or_list, waiting for the trace to complete, handling the output, etc. What I need is something that would be able to run like 4+ traces at the same time, storing the data retrieved from that in some way, so that I can process that data afterwards.

I am sure that there are methods to do this. I believe I would need something called asynchronous programming (?), for which I have done research.
I have found solutions talking about multi-threading or using the asyncio library, however I don't understand what the difference exactly is and what I would need for this problem.

All I ask, really, is which method I should use for this particular problem, so that I can properly research how it works and how I can apply it to my situation   without getting too confused.